# Laravel 5.2 Ajax Returns me undefined value, im doing an edit modal using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i need to show the values depending on the id, here is my button trigger for the edit, the jquery returns me a result when i console.log(result) it gives me data, but when i do console.log(result.company_name) and console.log(result[0].company_name) it gives me undefined, i tried many ways but still not working pls help, im trying to put the value in the modal input field

```
<button onclick="editClient({{$v->id}})" data-toggle="modal" data-
target="#editClientModal"></button>
```

here is my jquery ajax

```
 function editClient(id){
  var client_id = id;
  $.ajax({
    url: "{!!URL::to('/clients/edit')!!}/"+client_id,
     success: function( result ) {
       console.log(result.company_name);
       $("#company_name").val(result.company_name);
     }
   });
 }
```

here is my edit function in the controller

```
function getEditClient($id){
    $data = DB::table('clients')->find($id);

    return json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: console.log(result) .... whats your output ? can you provide ?

Comment: undefineddddddd

Comment: u said  the result give u data, but right now undifined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your ajax request just add `dataType: "JSON",`

```
 function editClient(id){
  var client_id = id;
  $.ajax({
    url: "{!!URL::to('/clients/edit')!!}/"+client_id,
    dataType: "JSON",
     success: function( result ) {
       console.log(result.company_name);
       $("#company_name").val(result.company_name);
     }
   });
 }
```

or if u dont include the `dataType`, in your success result should add   `JSON.parse(variable)`

```
JSON.parse(result)['company_name']
```